# MySQL order by the number of matches in an intermediate table

Tags: mysql, database

So I have a query that is trying to grab "related posts".

Categories have a one-to-many relationship with posts.  Tags have a many-to-many relationship.  So my tables look roughly like this:

```
posts table:
id | category_id | ... | ...

tags table:
id | ... | ...

post_tag intermediate table:
id | post_id | tag_id | ... | ...
```

So if I have a single Post row already, and what to grab its "related" posts.  My logic is roughly that I want to grab only posts that are in the same category, but to order those posts by the amount of tags that match the original post.  So another post in the same category that has the exact same tags as the original post, should be a very high match, whereas a post that only matches 3/4 of the tags will show up lower in the results.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts AS p
WHERE p.category_id=?
ORDER BY ( SELECT COUNT(id) 
           FROM post_tag AS i 
           WHERE i.tag_id IN( ? )
         )
LIMIT 5
```

BINDINGS:
  Initial Posts Category ID;
  Initial Posts Tag IDs;

Clearly this is not going to actually order the results by the correct values in the sub-select.  I am having trouble trying to think of how to join this to achieve the correct results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm really curious why you need the id in the post_tag table... you could just have set primary key to post_id, tag_id instead at least if that's all that table is used for anyway

Comment: @xception: He probably doesn't need a separate ID. A lot of people reflexively put surrogate IDs on every table, though.

Comment: @TomAnderson quite likely, still I think it was worth mentioning just in case he'll take it into consideration in future database table designs

Comment: @xception I almost always add the extra id, but you are absolutely correct, it is not necessary.  It does make it easier for managing the intermediate table though, i.e. deleting the row.  I am also using Laravel, which wants to have that by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I undestood your question correctly this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT p.*, 
       Count(pt.tag_id) AS ord 
FROM   posts AS currentpost 
       JOIN posts AS p 
         ON p.category_id = currentpost.category_id 
            AND p.id != currentpost.id 
       JOIN post_tag AS pt 
         ON pt.post_id = p.id 
            AND pt.tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id 
                              FROM   post_tag 
                              WHERE  post_id = currentpost.id) 
WHERE  currentpost.id = ? 
GROUP  BY p.id 
ORDER  BY ord DESC
```

BINDINGS: Initial `posts.id`;

and you only have to specify the id of the current post in my version so you don't have to fetch the posts tags beforehand and format them suitably for an in clause

EDIT:
This should be a faster query by avoiding double joining posts, if you don't like user variables just replace all currentpostid with ? and triple-bind post_id:

```
set @currentpostid = ?;
select p.*, count(pt.tag_id) as ord
from posts as p, 
join post_tag as pt
    on pt.post_id = p.id
    and pt.tag_id in (select tag_id from post_tag where post_id = @currentpostid)
where p.category_id = (select category_id from posts where id=@currentpostid)
    and p.id != @currentpostid
group by p.id
order by ord desc;
```

Comment: @ConarWelsh No problem, you selected the other answer as valid though :)

Comment: I thought I could select them both as correct.  I was curious to see which would be faster, but I think since I do not actually have the Tag Ids, without another query, this one will prevail.  I am going to do some profiling... mainly out of pure curiosity, because this is fast enough as is.

Comment: @ConarWelsh Let us know about your findings in that regard. I think this might get to be optimized better since I don't force an order on the select operations, but in the end it depends on indexes and possibly how large each of your tables are. Mine also eliminates the current post as I'm guessing you don't want that.

Comment: Yes your correct, I didn't mention it because I knew I could easily add that right in.  There are a few other things, like only grabbing published ones and whatnot, but they are easy.  Thanks!

Comment: @ConarWelsh mysql really sucks at estimating performance, that's why I love postgresql it has this extension to explain ... if you do `explain analyze query` it executes the query and tells you exactly how much it took and what the plan did, also it's more readable than mysql's explain output

Comment: Yea I know, but in the projects I usually run I am not fortunate enough to have that as an option.  Typically I will just run a loop with 1000 (or so) iterations from whatever framework I am in and check the overall execution time.  Not the most accurate way to test the DB, but it still provides me with basically the info I am looking for (given there is a handful of unwanted variables in the mix).

Comment: I tested both queries. The second query (@ankur) was faster, with an average speed of .0008, however the results were incorrect, the posts were not being ordered properly by the amount of matching tags.  The first query had an average speed of .0034, with correct results.  Thought I would share that one with you guys.  Thank you both for your help!  I went with the query by @xception.

Comment: @ConarWelsh Updated with a hopefully faster query, removed an extra join on posts which I suspect is a decently sized table, let me know the results if you benchmark this one as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
SELECT posts.* 
FROM   posts,(SELECT p.id, 
                     Count(pt.tag_id) AS count_tag 
              FROM   posts AS p, 
                     post_tag AS pt 
              WHERE  p.category_id = '***' 
                     AND pt.post_id = p.id 
                     AND pt.tag_id IN(SELECT tag_id 
                                      FROM   post_tag 
                                      WHERE  post_tag.post_id = '***') 
              GROUP  BY p.id 
              ) temp

WHERE  posts.id =temp.id ORDER  BY temp.count_tag desc
```

Where you can fill `***` as you already have 1 post row

Comment: Does it work with the `order by` inside the first subquery like that? I think that according to standard SQL rules, it doesn't have to; if it does, that's a specific feature (or quirk) of MySQL.

Comment: @TomAnderson I don't know, I tried it, had to fix tagid to be tag_id and received the following error afterwards `ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: I am going to test this one as well.  Since I already have the initial post model built out, I for sure already know the post id and category id, however since the tag relationships are in the intermediate table, I would have to do a `SELECT * FROM post_tag WHERE post_id=?` to get the tag IDs.  I am curious which would be faster.  I will be caching the results, but it is in a sidebar so it will get hit frequently.

Comment: @xception thanks for pointing out. Fixed the query, i forgot to join the two.

Comment: Re-tested, the current version works, with the tagid -> tag_id modification